# How to use cx_Oracle within AWS SageMaker (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cx-oracle, amazon-sagemaker

I've followed the official [installation guide](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux) but haven't had any luck so far. I wonder if `cx_Oracle` *can* work on AWS SageMaker's virtual environment. The steps I've used so far are:

1. Create a `/opt/oracle` directory and unzip the basic instantclient in it.
2. `sudo yum install libaio`
3. `sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"` and
   `sudo ldconfig`
4. And finally exported the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

When trying to run a connection inside the notebook with `connection = cx_Oracle.connect(usr + '/' + pwd + '@' + url)`, I receive the `DPI-1047` error code that says that `libclntsh.so` cannot be open, however that library *is* in the `/opt/oracle` folder. As another option, when running the same connection through the terminal Python console, I get the `ORA-01804` error code, which says that the timezone files were not properly read, which is something I'm trying to fix also but suspect is related to `cx_Oracle` not finding its library folder. (Now, explain to me: why does it have to be so difficult for a billionaire company to create a decent library import and installation?)

Is there a step I'm missing? Is there a detail about AWS SageMaker that I should account for? Also, is there another option for extracting data from an oracle server through Python and AWS?

Comment: If anyone knows someone who could solve this, I'm even prepared to pay a fair amount to know the solution to this problem.

Comment: I, too, am puzzled why Amazon would make it so hard for you.  I don't have any AWS experience so don't have a direct answer.  Three comments: (i) the cx_Oracle installation instructions are actually at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html (ii) you didn't give the exact error DPI message, which could have been helpful. (iii) you don't (shouldn't) need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH once you have configured ldconfig.

Comment: My comment was actually aiming at Oracle for making a library so prone to configuration errors (as are many other software they sell), but I guess it is also applicable to Amazon. (i) the link you posted has the same instructions as the tutorial I followed, which is the one they point to when you download the packages; (iii) you are correct, and I had forgotten about that, it's just that I did both because none of them would work.

Comment: (ii) the complete error is: `DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help`.

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but could you elaborate on where you exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? The Jupyter kernel session might not be sharing environment variables with your terminal session. (Alternatives are to move your steps into the notebook Lifecycle Config, or using `%env` directives)

Answer (score 2):

Hi and thank you for using SageMaker!

After some effort, I was finally able to figure out a sequence of steps that allowed me to query an Oracle 12 database from within a SageMaker notebook instance.  Here are the steps that I took:

1. I created an Oracle 12 database using [Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.Oracle.html) for testing purposes.  (You can of course skip this step if you already have an Oracle database available.)
2. I downloaded the **Oracle 12 Instant Client RPM** as described [here](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#id8).  Note that you will need an Oracle Account in order to download this file.
3. I uploaded the RPM to my SageMaker Notebook Instance from within JupyterLab.  Note that this can take 2-3 minutes to completely upload before proceeding to the next step.  (I initially had problems running the installation because the upload was still in progress.)
4. I ran all of the following commands from the Jupyter terminal as prescribed in the Oracle instructions:

```sh
cd SageMaker

sudo yum install oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/network/admin

# Restart Jupyter...
sudo restart jupyter-server
```

5. I then installed the [cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) library:

```sh
source activate python3
pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

6. Then lastly, I created a new notebook using the conda_python3 kernel:

```py
import cx_Oracle
db = cx_Oracle.connect("my_username/my_password@my-rds-instance.ccccccccccc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/ORCL")

# Example query
cursor = db.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute('select * from DBA_TABLES'):
  print(row)
```

...and then it worked!

Note that it took me a few tries to figure out the exact connection string, which can differ depending on how your database is configured.  Unfortunately, the error messages were hard to understand - in my case, I had the error *ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA* until I had specified the /ORCL at the end of the connection string.

If you need to do these steps frequently, you can add the installation and configuration of the Oracle client in a SageMaker [Lifecycle Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html) script.  I haven't tested that scenario, but it might be worth a try!

One last thing, I noticed in your question that you are using the Oracle 18 client.  I didn't test that exact scenario, since I only have access to an Oracle 12 database.  However, the Oracle 12 client should be able to connect to an Oracle 18 database, too.

Best,
Kevin

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I will give it a try as soon as I have some time available.

Comment: You can download Oracle Instant Client RPMs  from Oracle's yum server without needing an account or clickthrough: http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/index.html